# primeng p-dialog change URL on close button - angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

As per primeng close button html, href is pointing to #

```
<a *ngIf="closable" [ngClass]="{'ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all':true}" href="#" role="button" (click)="close($event)" (mousedown)="onCloseMouseDown($event)">
                    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></span>
</a>
```

My Piece of code is :

```
<p-dialog header="Student Confirmation" modal="true" appendTo="body" [resizable]="false">
```

How can we change default href from "#" to something else in angular?

Tried below solution, but doesn't work for me :

```
 public close(): void {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("../studentAssignments", { relativeTo: this.route });
        super.close();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried with this: `href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="close()"` instead of `href="#"  (click)="close($event)"`  Does this work for you???

Comment: This is coming with primeng itself, unable to change this html file

Comment: can you try this also: `(onAfterHide)="close()"` this will trigger after close event.

Comment: Close() is getting called but it is not navigating to URL using below piece of code. 
        this.router.navigateByUrl("../studentAssignments", { relativeTo: this.route });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be possible because this the default HTML of primeng's component.

What you can do in this case is you can call `onHide` function on dialog component and redirect to wherever you want like this

```
<p-dialog (onHide)="close()" header="Student Confirmation" modal="true" appendTo="body" [resizable]="false">

public close(): void {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("../studentAssignments", { relativeTo: this.route });
    }
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-close?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Tried this, but not working
        this.router.navigateByUrl("../studentAssignments", { relativeTo: this.route });

Comment: This should work, I tried on my local. Can you please check whether you function is calling or not on close?

Comment: @VaibhavSawant PLease check my updated answer with working example

Answer (score 0):

Remove `href="#"` from the code

**OR**

Add `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: This is href coming with primeng itself, you can't change manually unless you made changes in the library itself.

Comment: Ho can I change the behaviour then? Or the icon fa fa-close? Do you know, Pardeep?